# background-repeat: repeat-y; starting position CSS

Tags: css

I am using 2 backgrounds in a single div. The top one has a static height and width and it doesnt repeat, but it has a transparency. The bottom one is a white line of 1px height that needs to repeat-y. But since repeat-y takes the whole height of the containing div. It is also behind the transparant top background image. Is it possible to make it so the bottom image only starts repeating under the top background and not at the top left?

Oh and I am only allowed to touch the Css file, so adding divs is no option.

```
.box_area {
    width:925px;
    background: url(../../images/verloop.png), url(../../images/whiteback.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 284px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
    padding-left:25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding-right:7px;
    float:left;
}
```

This is what I have now but the background position doesnt do anything at the moment.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you set up a JSfiddle for this?

Comment: Check the CSS property `background-size`.

Comment: I can try, but i can't touch the HTML file. and it's quite a difficult situation to like rebuild :P

Comment: @SyncCircles It needs to keep repeating in height when the cms creates a page that is larger than the template, so I cant set a static height. If that makes sense

Comment: The `background-size` CSS property specifies the size of the background images. Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:before` selector to add a pseudo element and position and style it so as to have second background you mentioned. Assuming 518px is height of first background, here is sample CSS to place second background below first.

```
.box_area {
    width:925px;
    background: url(../../images/verloop.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 284px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left:25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding-right:7px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
.box_area:before {
    content: "";
    height: calc(100% - 518px);
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../../images/whiteback.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 518px;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-left:-25px; /* This is to counter the 25px left-padding in .box-container div */
}
```

Comment: with a little bit of change this worked quite good, but 100% height takes the height of the screen and not of the content. so if our cms creates higher content the background will stop. any idea?

Comment: If you specify `height:100%` for pseudo element, it will generate second element with height same as that of ".box_area" element (I guess that's why you see it occupying entire screen when contents are less). But as we are specifying `top:518px`, i.e. place this pseudo element 518px below top of ".box_area" element, I specified height 518px less than 100%, `height: calc(100% - 518px);`. Note that I have assumed 518px as height of verloop.png. Replace that number with actual height of that image at both places above.

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom set `position: relative` to the parent element.